# JDBC: difference between socketTimeout and networkTimeout

Tags: java, mysql, jdbc

What is the difference between [socketTimeout](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/connector-j/5.1/en/connector-j-reference-configuration-properties.html) on JDBC URL and [networkTimeout](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/sql/Connection.html#setNetworkTimeout(java.util.concurrent.Executor,%20int)) on java.sql.Connection

Comment: Thanks @T.J.Crowder  - updated link

Answer (score 2):

The `Connection.networkTimeout` was introduced in Java 7, and is intended for the driver to take care of correct cleanup (using the provided executor). I'm not sure how well this method is supported by driver implementations.

On the other hand, `socketTimeout` is driver specific (although most drivers have a similar setting) and is - usually - used to configure the low-level socket timeout using [`Socket.setSoTimeout(int)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/net/Socket.html#setSoTimeout-int-).

The main difference is that the `setNetworkTimeout` specifies the behavior expected from a driver after occurrence of this timeout (invalidate and close the connection), while the `socketTimeout` config might just leave your connection in limbo (ie it might appear open, but isn't usable). `setNetworkTimeout` also allows for changing the timeout while the connection is already opened.